Problems in understanding the very first step of deriving canonical transformation properties
I'm reading the textbook "Classical Mechanics" by Alexei Deriglazov and I'm stuck on the following step. The author is using the definition of canonical transformation as a variable change $Z=Z(z,t)$ ($z$ and $Z$ vectors are formed, as usual, by concatenating  $q, p$ and $Q, P$ respectively) such that for every hamiltonian system $$\dot{z}=\mathbb{J}\nabla_z{H(z,t)},$$ a hamiltonian $K(Z,t)$ exists which allows the system to be represented in the new coordinates as $$\dot{Z}=\mathbb{J}\nabla_Z{K(Z,t)}.$$ Then he shows that, comparing the evolution of $Z$ vector in the two coordinate systems (with repeated indices summed), one obtains for the $Z_k$ coordinate (I've adjusted the notation slightly):
$$
\left\{Z_k,Z_l\right\}_z|_{z(Z,t)}\frac{\partial{H(z(Z,t))}}{\partial{Z_l}}+\frac{\partial{Z(z,t)}}{\partial{t}}\Big{|}_{z(Z,t)}=\mathbb{J}_{kl}\frac{\partial{K(Z,t)}}{\partial{Z_l}}.
$$
This latter is essentially a chain rule exercise but then he asserts

From this expression we immediately obtain two useful consequences. First, taking derivative $\frac{\partial{}}{\partial{Z_k}}$ [...]

And he writes:
$$
\frac{\partial{}}{\partial{Z_k}}\left(\left\{Z_k,Z_l\right\}_z|_{z(Z,t)}\right)\frac{\partial{H(z(Z,t))}}{\partial{Z_l}}+\frac{\partial{}}{\partial{Z_k}}\left(\frac{\partial{Z(z,t)}}{\partial{t}}\Big{|}_{z(Z,t)}\right)=0.
$$
At this point, I'm confused about what he is doing. Is he summing over the index $k$ or not? Also, why does the derivative only operate at last on the first factor (the Poisson bracket) and not on the term involving $H$? Deriving the right side should involve directly second partial derivatives of $K$ with respect to the $Z$ and so it seems to me that the $1$ and $-1$ terms could cancel out in case of summing over $k$, but it is just a guess about how the expression might be manipulated.
I suppose there is some simplification but I am not able to find it "immediately".

I guess the point is that the Poisson bracket anticommute, while the second derivative of $H$ with respect to $Z_l$ and $Z_k$ is symmetric, thus the product of these two factors gives zero.

So he's evaluating by summing over $k$, right? Going just a little further, from the last equation the author deduces that all Poisson bracket derivatives are $0$ (because the expression, he says, should be true for any $H$), but if the interpretation is correct, can't we only say that suitable $2d$-term sums of those derivatives are $0$?

@QuestionAsker To show that all ${Z_k,Z_l}$ are only functions of time, the Author does this explicitly for the case $2d=2$ at page 138 of the cited textbook: but, it's clear that having just one Poisson bracket leads to the condition $\frac{\partial{{Q,P}}}{\partial{Q}}\frac{\partial{H}}{\partial{P}}-\frac{\partial{{Q,P}}}{\partial{P}}\frac{\partial{H}}{\partial{Q}}=0$, that, due to $H$ arbitrariness, forces ${Q,P}$ to be a function only of time. But with e.g. $2d=4$ we'll have six Poisson brackets to be constrained by only four independent variations (the partial derivatives of $H$)

So, in summary both equations (or sets of equations, varying $H/K$) probably play a role in the result: note that $\mathbb J_{k\ell}$ vanishes if $k\neq \bar\ell$ (where $\bar \ell$ is the index conjugate $\ell$), and $K(Z,t)$ must have the same level-set (energy hypersurface) structure as $H(z(Z,t))$ (to preserve the canonical equations of motion), so $\partial_Z K\propto \partial_Z H$.  Therefore, for "restricted" transformations (in which $\partial_tZ(z,t) = 0$) you would automatically have $\{Z_k,Z_\ell\} = 0$ for $k\neq \bar\ell$. These extra conditions might be what you were missing, but only if $Z(z,t)$ has no explicit time-dependence (i.e. $Z$ depends on $z$ alone: also, I'm not one hundred percent certain that $K(Z)$ must necessarily have the same level sets as $H(Z)$ for an arbitrary new set of canonical coordinates, only that it should for a simple coordinate transformation of phase space: for some reason, invoking this observation feels a little bit like cheating.)
